# How do I make a complicated table with LaTex?

Tags: tables, tabularx, booktabs, excel2latex

I want to create table like this but I am having some troubles doing it. I tried to use the `Excel2LaTex` plugin but it doesn't create the table I want in `LaTeX`.

[image]

Comment: Please show your approach as LaTeX code and resulting table.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Is there any specific aspect that gives you trouble? Could you elaborate on what you tried?

Comment: Do you want lines with variable thickness and colour, as shown in the image?

Comment: Hey, yes I want the lines and the thickness. I really have nothing to show because I tried the multicolumn and multiwors commands and the latex couldn't compile it so I am doing something wrong

Comment: If you're looking for an easy GUI this webpage could be of help. https://www.tablesgenerator.com/ Also, since there's no real "why" here, rather a "how" I'm voting to close this question because it's either not focused or opinion based.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend to use the `booktabs` package for this kind of table. For further reading have a look at the [manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs).

```
\documentclass[varwidth=\maxdimen]{standalone}

 \usepackage{booktabs,multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp!]
        \begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}}
            \toprule
            \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Heat transfer resistance}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Direction of heat flow rate}}      \\ \cmidrule{2-5} 
            & upward & horizontal & downward & contact with ground \\ \midrule
            R\_\{si\} & 0.1 & 0.13 & 0.17 & 0 \\
            R\_\{se\} & 0.04 & 0.04 & 0.04 & 0 \\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, there are other [sides](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/#), where you can generate such complicated tables.

**EDIT**

In case you agree with @egreg, I changed the code slightly.

```
\documentclass[varwidth=\maxdimen]{standalone}

\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp!]
        \begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}}
            \toprule
            & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Direction of heat flow rate}} \\ \cmidrule(l){2-5} 
            \textbf{Heat transfer resistance} & upward & horizontal & downward & contact with ground \\ \midrule
            R\_\{si\} & 0.1 & 0.13 & 0.17 & 0 \\
            R\_\{se\} & 0.04 & 0.04 & 0.04 & 0 \\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to add to this answer (which looks almost exactly like my approach) that vertical lines in tables should be used sparingly as they are an obstacle to the flow of the reader and that is why they haven't been used here.

Comment: +1, but I'd avoid `\multirow` and simply place the two boldface headers at the same level (and perhaps remove boldfacing). A further improvement might be `\cmidrule(l){2-5}` to trim the rule at its left edge.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for your suggestions. I added your alternative table in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, based on `tabularx`,  `booktabs` *and* `hhline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{hhline}
\newcommand{\vblack}{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{Gainsboro}}}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\centering\sffamily
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{!{\color{Gainsboro}\vrule}l!{\vrule width 0.05em} >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X!{\color{Gainsboro}\vrule}>{\hsize=0.95\hsize}X!{\color{Gainsboro}\vrule}>{\hsize=1.05\hsize}X!{\color{Gainsboro}\vrule}>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X|}
\arrayrulecolor{Gainsboro}\toprule[0.3pt]\arrayrulecolor{black}
 & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\bfseries Direction of heat flow rate} \\[-0.08em]
\cmidrule[0.05em]{2-5}
 \bfseries Heat transfer resistance & \makecell[lb]{upward} & \makecell[lb]{horizontal} & \makecell[lb]{downward} & \makecell[lb]{\rlap{contact with ground}} \\
\midrule[0.08em]
 R\_{si} & 0.1\phantom{0} & 0.13 & 0.17 & 0 \\
 \arrayrulecolor{Gainsboro}
\hhline{|->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{Gainsboro}}-|-|-|->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|} %\midrule
 R\_{se} & 0.04 & 0.04 & 0.04 & 0 \\
\arrayrulecolor{black} \midrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'd avoid vertical rules that serve no purpose and are actually of a hindrance to reading.

We can spare some space by splitting the first header into two lines.

Using `siunitx` features allows for better positioning of the figures.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\newcommand{\doubleheader}[1]{%
  \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  *{3}{S[table-format=1.2]}
  S[table-format=1.0]
  @{}
}
\toprule
\doubleheader{Heat transfer \\ resistance} &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Direction of heat flow rate} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-5} 
& {upward} & {horizontal} & {downward} & {contact with ground} \\
\midrule
$R_{\mathrm{si}}$ &  0.1 & 0.13 & 0.17 & 0 \\
$R_{\mathrm{se}}$ & 0.04 & 0.04 & 0.04 & 0 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]